# SQL query works sometimes

Tags: sql

I have this query and it seems to work most of the time, but I am still getting NULLs with it when I know it should return something,

I start with `select`, then this

```
(select sum(total) from orders
        where customer = 9
        and iscredit = 1
        and isdeleted = false and not id = 1560)
```

this peace of code gets me a total amount of orders for customer 9 and is not the current order, like a previous orders total...also notice that iscredit = 1 meaning that these are credit orders.

Next I want to add this query

```
(select sum(total) from orders
        where customer = 9
        and iscredit = 0
        and isdeleted = false and not id = 1560)
```

does the same thing but iscredit is 0 so orders that are not credits.

next I want to subtract what has been paid with this query

```
- (select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) from payment p
        inner join orders o
        on p.order = o.id
        where o.customer = 9) as previous
```

So all together this what my query looks like....

```
select 
(
    select sum(total) 
    from orders
    where customer = 9 and iscredit = 1 and isdeleted = false and not id = 1560
) 
+ 
(
    select sum(total) 
    from orders
    where customer = 9 and iscredit = 0 and isdeleted = false and not id = 1560
) 
- 
(
    select ifnull(sum(p.amount), 0) 
    from payment p
        inner join orders o
            on p.order = o.id
    where o.customer = 9
) as previous
```

Is there a better way to write this?

Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will lump the first two totals together.

```
(select sum(total)
from orders
where customer = 0
and (iscredit = 1 or iscredit = 0)
and isdeleted = false
and not id = 1560)
```

This will return null for no matching rows, so you might want to add:

```
(select ifnull(sum(total), 0)
from orders
where customer = 0
and (iscredit = 1 or iscredit = 0)
and isdeleted = false
and not id = 1560)
```

This is probably the source of your problems.